# NTL convert ZZX to ZZ_pEX

Tags: c++, ntl

In NTL, I've the following variables:

```
ZZ p;
ZZX FX;
ZZX GX;
```

and I want to calculate

```
GCD(GX, FX) over F_p(x)
```

How can I convert `FX` and `GX` into a F_p(x) polynomial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `conv(T out, S in)`.

`conv` is defined for many pairs of type.
You can find a list of all combinations [here](http://www.shoup.net/ntl/doc/conversions.txt).

I assume by `F_p(x)` you mean `ZZ_pX` or `ZZ_pEX`.